# Create custom view with constraints and initializing with frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, frame

I need to create a custom view like this (small view over current controller background) and load it programatically:

[image]

I used to create full-size custom views, and the problem I have now is that I'm not sure about how to handle frame vs constraints in smaller ones that depend also on the parent view controller.

I would need to set the frame of the view in its init(), so it has some margins in relation to the background frame, and it also needs to have a flexible height depending on the size of the text (so I can't use only a fixed frame, its size must depend on the text)

If I pass the frame in its init(), it doesn't respect the flexible height, and if I use translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, it doesn't respect the position over the background view.

Is there any way to combine both?

Comment: You can use constraints to position your view, not just to size it. Any reason why you can't do it all with constraints?

Comment: @Clafou from the custom view to its parent in the xib file?

Comment: Yes but if the view and its parent are not in the same XIB you will have to create the constraints programmatically, not in Interface Builder.

Comment: @Clafou Ok I was trying to avoid that and handle everything in the storyboard, I'll try your approach, thanks!